# How to filter a matrix by the value of another

Tags: r, matrix

I have 2 matrices: `m1` and `m2`.

`m1`:

```
    1   2   3   4   5
1  v11 v12 v13 v14 v15
2  v21 v22 v23 v24 v25
3  v31 v32 v33 v34 v35 
4  v41 v42 v43 v44 v45
5  v51 v52 v53 v54 v55
```

`m2`:

```
 x1, x2
 1   1
 1   2
 1   4
 2   2
 2   3    
 2   5
```

I would like to only keep `m1` if the rowname and colname is found in `m2`, otherwise, I would like to write "NA" to the location

e.g. the result should be:

m1:

```
    1   2   3   4   5
1  v11 v12 NA  v14  NA
2  NA  v22 v23  NA v25
3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 
4  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
5  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

So far I tried to use:

```
m1[!(rownames(m1) %in% m2$x1 & colnames(m1) %in% m1$x2)]<-NA
```

The result is not right? Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you clarify whether the values in `m2` are the indices or whether they are the `dimnames` of your data (which are, unfortunately in this example, the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my old answer I thought the OP wanted to select the specific elements from the `m1`, based on `m2`. Hong Ooi's answer works really well if the dimnames of `m1` line up with with the row and column indices, and `m2` contains integers and not character values. Here is a rough solution for if they do not necessarily line up.

```
m1 <- matrix(c("V11","V21","V12","V22","V13","V23"),nrow=2,ncol=3)
dimnames(m1) <- list(c("r2","r1"),c("c1","c2","c3"))
m2 <- matrix(c("r1","r1","r2","c1","c3","c3"),nrow=3,ncol=2)

> m1
   c1    c2    c3   
r2 "V11" "V12" "V13"
r1 "V21" "V22" "V23"

> m2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "r1" "c1"
[2,] "r1" "c3"
[3,] "r2" "c3"

temp <- matrix(TRUE,nrow=nrow(m1),ncol=ncol(m1))

for(i in 1:nrow(m2)){
  temp[which(rownames(m1)==m2[i,1]),which(colnames(m1)==m2[i,2])] <- FALSE
}

m1[temp] <- NA

> m1
   c1    c2 c3    
r2 NA    NA "V13"
r1 "V21" NA "V23"
```

**Old Answer:**

```
m1 <- matrix(c("V11","V21","V12","V22","V13","V23"),nrow=2,ncol=3)

> m1
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
[1,] "V11" "V12" "V13"
[2,] "V21" "V22" "V23"

m2 <- matrix(c(1,1,2,1,3,3),nrow=3,ncol=2)

> m2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    2    3

keep <- paste(paste0(m2[,1],m2[,2]),collapse="|")
m1[!grepl(keep,m1)] <- NA

> m1
     [,1]  [,2] [,3] 
[1,] "V11" NA   "V13"
[2,] NA    NA   "V23"
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
m1[!grepl(paste(paste0(m2[,1],m2[,2]),collapse="|"),m1)] <- NA
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing some data to work with, but your result doesn't appear to be correct.

Comment: @AnandaMahto please see edit. I believe it is correct now. I initialized `m1` incorrectly.

Comment: Interesting answer. I hadn't thought of the numbers in "m2" being representative of a part of the name. I assumed they were the indices of rows and columns to match (or alternatively, the rownames and column names, as they indicate in their attempted solution).

Comment: @AnandaMahto Oh! I see what you mean. My answer definitely ignores the dimnames. In a sense so does the answer provided by Hong Ooi as well, because his/her answer only considers the row/column index.

Comment: +1 for going the extra mile :). Another alternative, create a new "matches" matrix like this `matches <- cbind(match(m2[, 1], rownames(m1)), match(m2[, 2], colnames(m1)))` and use @HongOoi's approach (ie, create a matrix of `NA`, and then use `m3[matches] <- m1[matches]`).

Comment: @AnandaMahto I knew there would be a better non-for loop solution. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I can come up with a two-liner:

```
m <- m1[NA,]
m[m2] <- m1[m2]
```